# Start Thread in OnCreate of Form / Frame with Handle of this Form

Tags: delphi

I have a problem that I don't know how to fix.

I try to start a thread in the `OnCreate` event, or after creating a `TFrame` when its `Parent` is still `nil`. When creating the thread, I pass it a window handle, but the address of the window changes after e.g. the `OnShow` event.

```
procedure Form1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TCustomThread.Create(Self);
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Self.Handle); //for example 10203040 
end;

procedure Form1.ButtonOnClick;
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Self.Handle); //i give 342545454 not 10203040 
end;

procedure Form1.FromThread(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_TheardComplete;
begin
  {do something}
end;

constructor TCustomThread.Create(AWinControl: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FWinControl := AWinControl;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
   {do something}
   PostMessage(FWinControl.Handle, WM_TheardComplete, 0, 0); //Handle 10203040
end;
```

What parameter can I use to start the thread so that it can later send messages to this object?

Comment: Nitpick: A handle isn't an address.

Comment: This is normal. The VCL sometimes re-creates windows. Don't have the thread take a reference to the window handle. Have it take a reference to the form. And then use `TThread.Queue` to post a message.

Comment: Try solving a problem instead of [biting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bite#English) it. :)

Comment: Why do you need the form handle? I understand you need it to PostMessage to pass some information. Since handle refering to an actual window are sometimes recreated, it becomes invalid in your thread. To solve the problem, you can create a new handle to tied to an actual window. That handle will not be recreated. Use System.Classes.AllocateHwnd.

Answer (score 2):

The `TWinControl.Handle` property is NOT thread-safe. The VCL can, and does, recreate a control's window dynamically during the control's lifetime, even multiple times.  But more importantly, windows have thread affinity, where message retrieval and processing for a given window only works in the thread that creates the window. A worker thread using a control's `Handle` property causes a race condition that, if you are not careful, can actually cause the worker thread to capture ownership of the control's window, rendering the control completely useless in the main UI thread.

If you need to give a worker thread a window to post/send messages to, give the thread a *persistent* window that the VCL won't destroy (without you telling it to), for instance by using the [main `TApplication` window](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Handle), using its [`OnMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnMessage) event to handle posted messages, or its [`HookMainWindow()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HookMainWindow) method to handle sent messages, eg:

```pascal
procedure Form1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnMessage := AppMessage;
  TCustomThread.Create(Application.Handle);
end;

procedure Form1.OnDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnMessage := nil;
end;

procedure Form1.AppMessage(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message = WM_TheardComplete then
  begin
    Handled := True;
    {do something}
  end;
end;

constructor TCustomThread.Create(AWnd: HWND);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FWnd := AWnd;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
   {do something}
   PostMessage(FWnd, WM_TheardComplete, 0, 0);
end;
```

Or better, use a new dedicated window created with the VCL's  [`AllocateHWnd()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd) function, eg:

```pascal
procedure Form1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ThreadWnd := AllocateHWnd(ThreadWndProc);
  TCustomThread.Create(ThreadWnd);
end;

procedure Form1.OnDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(ThreadWnd);
end;

procedure Form1.ThreadWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_TheardComplete then
  begin
    {do something}
  end else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(ThreadWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

constructor TCustomThread.Create(AWnd: HWND);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FWnd := AWnd;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
   {do something}
   PostMessage(FWnd, WM_TheardComplete, 0, 0);
end;
```

However, in the example you have presented, rather than sending a message at the end of the thread's execution, I would suggest a completely different approach - use the `TThread.OnTerminate` event instead, which is already synced with the main thread, eg:

```pascal
procedure Form1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread: TCustomThread;
begin
  Thread := TCustomThread.Create;
  Thread.OnTerminate := ThreadFinished;
  Thread.Start; // or Resume() in older versions
end;

procedure Form1.ThreadFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {do something}
end;

constructor TCustomThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
begin
   {do something}
end;
```

Alternatively, in modern versions of Delphi, consider using [`TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) instead, eg:

```pascal
procedure Form1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread: TThread;
begin
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      {do something}
    end
  );
  Thread.OnTerminate := ThreadFinished;
  Thread.Start;
end;

procedure Form1.ThreadFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {do something}
end;
```

Or even:

```pascal
procedure Form1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      try
        {do something}
      finally
        TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            {do something}
          end
       );
      end;
    end
  ).Start;
end;
```